# How to reproduce fitted ARIMA(0,1,1) values?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, fitting

I am using R's forecast package's auto.arima function to forecast the following time series:

```
kappa_fem
 [1]  2.50594398  2.41561580  2.01398417  1.48457404  2.04769840  2.01201415  1.64096776  1.57316001
 [9]  1.52310538  0.59070658  0.39113565  0.05752619 -0.22008153 -0.29964353 -0.74587944 -1.66680655
[17] -1.58850370 -1.45096124 -1.86077396 -1.37769777 -2.23703721 -1.82095112 -2.07108890 -2.91700716
```

auto.arima gives the following ARIMA(0,1,1) model as output:

```
> kappa_arima_fem <- auto.arima(kappa_fem)
> kappa_arima_fem
Series: kappa_fem 
ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 

Coefficients:
          ma1    drift
      -0.4577  -0.2268
s.e.   0.2111   0.0444

sigma^2 estimated as 0.156:  log likelihood=-10.34
AIC=26.69   AICc=27.95   BIC=30.1
```

So if I understand correctly, the time series has the following recursive formula:
$$
\kappa_t-\kappa_{t-1}=-0.2268+\epsilon_t-0.4577\epsilon_{t-1}.
$$

The model's fitted values are as follows:

```
> kappa_arima_fem$fitted
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 24 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  2.50321121  2.29149831  2.13496208  1.84024726  1.42041545  1.53407498  1.56648427  1.38005488
 [9]  1.25795540  1.17492659  0.63126371  0.27421034 -0.07012882 -0.37827790 -0.56245865 -0.88875828
[17] -1.53753883 -1.79200440 -1.83387450 -2.07528881 -1.92379434 -2.32049963 -2.27640843 -2.39188475
```

I try to reproduce them by hand:

```
fit_kappa_fem <- kappa_fem[1]
for(t in 2:length(kappa_fem)){
  fit_kappa_fem[t] <- fit_kappa_fem[t-1]+coef(kappa_arima_fem)[2]+coef(kappa_arima_fem)[1]*(fit_kappa_fem[t-1]-kappa_fem[t-1])
}
fit_kappa_fem
```

which gives me the following similar yet different values:

```
> fit_kappa_fem
 [1]  2.50594398  2.27911790  2.11476359  1.84181321  1.45148743  1.49753263  1.50617225  1.34103880
 [9]  1.22044895  1.13214137  0.65751373  0.30877287 -0.03304272 -0.34547192 -0.55132346 -0.86719309
[17] -1.45998284 -1.74562980 -1.83759324 -2.07502857 -1.98270328 -2.32593183 -2.32164050 -2.43379520
```

My questions are:

1) How are these fitted values calculated?

2) Why is the first fitted value different then the first value of the original time series kappa_fem?

3) I want to simulate $\kappa_{25}$ with $\epsilon_{25}=-0.3415483$. How would I go about this correctly?

Many thanks!